# Antd table select not working, always selecting all the rows

Tags: antd

I am trying to implement row selection in my antd table but when I am selecting any rows all the rows gets selected

```
 <PhcTable
                                pagination={false}
                                dataSource={configurationOptions?.ConfigDeposits[index].creditTiers}
                                columns={columnsPaymentPlans}
                                rowSelection={{onselect:(record)=>{console.log(record)}}}
                                scroll={{ x: 500 }}
                              />
```

const columnsPaymentPlans = [

```
{
  title: "Credit Tiers",
  dataIndex: 'creditTier',
  key: 'creditTier',
  width: 80
},
{
  title: "Credit Risk",
  dataIndex: "CreditRisk",
  key: "CreditRisk",
  width: 60,
},
{
  title: "Notes",
  dataIndex: "notes",
  key: "notes",
  width: 100,
},
{
  title: "Deposit",
  dataIndex: "deposit",
  key: "deposit",
  width: 60,
  fixed: "right",
  render: (text, record, index) => (
    <PhcForm.Item
      initialValue={text}
      name={`deposit${record.providerSpecialtyId.toString()+index.toString()}`}
      rules={[
        { required: true, message: "Field is required" },
        {
          validator: (rule, value, callback) =>
            validateDeposit(rule, value, callback, record,"%"),
        },
      ]}
    >
      <PhcInputNumber
        maxLength={4}
        style={{
          height: "40px",
          width: isBrowser ? "75%" : "100%",
          padding: "4px 11px",
        }}            
        value={text}
        //onChange={onInputChange("minDepositType", index)}
      />
    </PhcForm.Item>
  ),
},
{
  title: "Max Loan Amount",
  dataIndex: "maxLoanAmount",
  key: "maxLoanAmount",
  width: 70,
  fixed: "right",
  render: (text, record, index) => (
    <PhcForm.Item
      initialValue={text}
      name={`maxLoanAmount${record.providerSpecialtyId.toString()+index.toString()}`}
      rules={[
        { required: true, message: "Field is required" },
        {
          validator: (rule, value, callback) =>
            validateMaxLoanAmount(rule, value, callback, record),
        },
      ]}
    >
      <PhcInputDecimal
        keyboard={true}
        controls={true}
        onKeyPress={onNumberPress}
        formatter={(value) =>
          `${value}`.replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$($1)')
        }
        maxLength={5}
        style={{
          height: "40px",
          //width: isBrowser && "75%",
          width: isBrowser ? "75%" : "100%",
          padding: "4px 11px",
          //minWidth: "218px",
        }}
        value={text}
        //onChange={onInputChange("maxLoanAmount", index)}
      />
    </PhcForm.Item>
  ),
},
{
  title: "Terms",
  dataIndex: "Terms",
  key: "configDepositsTermsIds",
  width: 150,
  render: (text, record, index) => (
    <PhcForm.Item
      initialValue={record.Terms.filter(x=>x.selected == true).map(x=>x.id)}
      name={`ConfigDepositsTermsIds${record.providerSpecialtyId.toString()+index.toString()}`}
      rules={[
        { required: true, message: "Field is required" },
        {
          validator: (rule, value, callback) =>
            validateDeposit(rule, value, callback, record),
        },
      ]}
    >
      <PhcSelect
        mode="multiple"
        optionFilterProp="label"
        allowClear
        showSearch
        showArrow
        style={{ width: isBrowser && "75%" }}
      >
        {record.Terms &&
          record.Terms.map((item) => (
            <PhcSelect.Option value={item.id} label={item.term}>
              {item.term}
            </PhcSelect.Option>
          ))}
      </PhcSelect>
    </PhcForm.Item>
  ),
}
```

];

"creditTiers": [
{
"providerSpecialtyId": 1735,
"creditTierId": 1,
"creditTier": "Tier 1 Credit - Prime",
"CreditRisk": "Low",
"notes": "This credit tier serves near-prime, prime, and super-prime.",
"deposit": 0,
"maxLoanAmount": 20000,
"selected": false,
"Terms": [
{
"id": 1,
"term": "6",
"selected": false
},
{
"id": 2,
"term": "12",
"selected": false
},
{
"id": 3,
"term": "18",
"selected": false
},
{
"id": 4,
"term": "24",
"selected": false
},
{
"id": 5,
"term": "36",
"selected": false
},
{
"id": 6,
"term": "48",
"selected": false
},
{
"id": 7,
"term": "60",
"selected": false
}
]
},
{
"providerSpecialtyId": 1735,
"creditTierId": 2,
"creditTier": "Tier 2 Credit - Sub-Prime",
"CreditRisk": "Low/Moderate",
"notes": "This credit tier also serves low-income applicants.",
"deposit": 10,
"maxLoanAmount": 20000,
"selected": false,
"Terms": [
{
"id": 1,
"term": "6",
"selected": false
},
{
"id": 2,
"term": "12",
"selected": false
},
{
"id": 3,
"term": "18",
"selected": false
},
{
"id": 4,
"term": "24",
"selected": false
},
{
"id": 5,
"term": "36",
"selected": false
},
{
"id": 6,
"term": "48",
"selected": false
},
{
"id": 7,
"term": "60",
"selected": false
}
]
},
{
"providerSpecialtyId": 1735,
"creditTierId": 3,
"creditTier": "Tier 3 Credit - Deep Sub-Prime",
"CreditRisk": "Moderate/High",
"notes": "This credit tier is best used with orthodontics.",
"deposit": 15,
"maxLoanAmount": 15000,
"selected": false,
"Terms": [
{
"id": 1,
"term": "6",
"selected": false
},
{
"id": 2,
"term": "12",
"selected": false
},
{
"id": 3,
"term": "18",
"selected": false
},
{
"id": 4,
"term": "24",
"selected": false
},
{
"id": 5,
"term": "36",
"selected": false
},
{
"id": 6,
"term": "48",
"selected": false
},
{
"id": 7,
"term": "60",
"selected": false
}
]
},
{
"providerSpecialtyId": 1735,
"creditTierId": 4,
"creditTier": "Tier 4 Credit - Underbanked",
"CreditRisk": "Moderate/High",
"notes": "Applicants may use a SS# or an ITIN# to apply.",
"deposit": 15,
"maxLoanAmount": 7500,
"selected": false,
"Terms": [
{
"id": 1,
"term": "6",
"selected": false
},
{
"id": 2,
"term": "12",
"selected": false
},
{
"id": 3,
"term": "18",
"selected": false
},
{
"id": 4,
"term": "24",
"selected": false
},
{
"id": 5,
"term": "36",
"selected": false
},
{
"id": 6,
"term": "48",
"selected": false
},
{
"id": 7,
"term": "60",
"selected": false
}
]
},
{
"providerSpecialtyId": 1735,
"creditTierId": 5,
"creditTier": "Tier 5 Credit - Last Resort",
"CreditRisk": "High",
"notes": "Limits dental repayment options to 2, 3, and 4 months.",
"deposit": 20,
"maxLoanAmount": 7500,
"selected": false,
"Terms": [
{
"id": 1,
"term": "6",
"selected": false
},
{
"id": 2,
"term": "12",
"selected": false
},
{
"id": 3,
"term": "18",
"selected": false
},
{
"id": 4,
"term": "24",
"selected": false
},
{
"id": 5,
"term": "36",
"selected": false
},
{
"id": 6,
"term": "48",
"selected": false
},
{
"id": 7,
"term": "60",
"selected": false
}
]
}
]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't specify key for each row. By default, antd find `key` in each row. Since you don't have it and according to the data you added above, the key is `creditTierId`. So you can specify row key in table by:

`rowKey={(record) => record.creditTierId}`

If you just enable rowSelection, you can select any row. But in order to know the rows you have selected, you can create a state and control the rowSelection. Please check the code. I use onChange function in rowSelection and it provides two arguments. The first one array of selected Row keys & second one selected rows.

```
function App() {
    const [selectedRowKeys, setSelectedRowKeys] = useState([]);

    const columnsPaymentPlans = [
        {
            title: 'Credit Tiers',
            dataIndex: 'creditTier',
            key: 'creditTier',
            width: 80
        },
        {
            title: 'Credit Risk',
            dataIndex: 'CreditRisk',
            key: 'CreditRisk',
            width: 60
        },
        {
            title: 'Notes',
            dataIndex: 'notes',
            key: 'notes',
            width: 100
        },
    // ...Other Columns
    ];

    return (
        <Table
            pagination={false}
            dataSource={configurationOptions?.creditTiers}
            columns={columnsPaymentPlans}
            rowKey={(record) => record.creditTierId}
            rowSelection={{
                selectedRowKeys,
                onChange: (selectedRowKeys, selectedRows) => {
                    setSelectedRowKeys(selectedRowKeys);
                }
            }}
            scroll={{ x: 500 }}
        />
    );
}

export default App;
```